# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and '[Int]'

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to write code that will update my array and give total pay based on the daily pay. I'm getting an error about binary operators so how do I fix this line code so that doesn't happen.

```
for day in stride(from: 1, to: 31, by: 1)
{
    dailyPay[day] = [Int(pay)]
    pay*=2
    if(day==1)
    {
        totalPay[day] = Int(pay)
    }
    else
    {

        totalPay[day] = totalPay[day-1]+dailyPay[day]//The problem is Here

        print("\(heade) \(day) \(head) \(dailyPay[day]) \(total) \(totalPay[day])")
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't show the declarations of your variables, but it appears that `totalPay` is an array of `Int`s, whereas `dailyPay` is a two-dimensional array of arrays of `Int`. So, `totalPay[day-1]` will be an `Int`, whereas `dailyPay[day]` will be an `[Int]`, or an array of `Int`s. The error you're getting therefore means exactly what it says; you can't use `+` to add an `Int` and an array.

From your code, it appears that `dailyPay` is probably meant to be a plain old array of integers, like `totalPay`. So you could fix this by changing the declaration, whereever it is, from:

```
var dailyPay: [[Int]]
```

to:

```
var dailyPay: [Int]
```

Then, change the assignment to:

```
dailyPay[day] = Int(pay)
```

and things should work.

Sidenote: Your `for` loop is needlessly complex. There's no need for `stride`, when you can just:

```
for day in 1...31
```

Comment: These are my variable decalrations:var pay = 0.01
var totalPay : [Int] = [0]
var dailyPay = [[Int]](repeating: [Int]( repeating: 1, count: 31), count:31)
var heade = "Day#: "
var head = "Pay: $"
var total = "Total Pay: $"

Comment: I know your code reproduces the same range as OP's code range but OP is probably trying to loop from 1 through 31 (inclusive)

Comment: So I tried your fixes but now I'm getting a new error of Contextual type 'Int' cannot be used with array literal.

Comment: And you need to initialize the array before appending an element

Comment: So I did initialize the array using: var dailyPay = [[Int]](repeating: [Int]( repeating: 1, count: 31), count:31) but I still get the error about binary operators with it.

Comment: @LeoDabus You're right; I was just reproducing the effect of the original code. I've edited it.

Comment: @VeraBoukhonine That still produces an array of arrays. Is there a reason you want that, instead of just, say, `[Int](repeating: 1, count: 31)`?